# Rails - setting up relationship between 3 models and do query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am trying to build a relationship basically as follows:

Group Model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
has_many :posts
```

User Model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
has_many :posts
```

Post Model

```
belongs_to :group
belongs_to :user
```

When I query about posts by the user, I can do user.posts. However, I can't figure out how to query all posts from the groups that the user joined. Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  has_many :posts
  has_many :group_posts, through: :groups, source: :posts
end
```

Comment: How about the query for all posts from the groups that the user joined?

Comment: Getting error, it says "Could not find the source association(s) :group_post or :group_posts in model Post

Comment: Did you add source option?

Answer (score 0):

Some further reading for you: **[has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)**

[image: has_many :through relationship]

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```